# how can i get xml file as a response from jsp

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

```
BufferedHttpServletResponse bufferedHttpServletResponse = new BufferedHttpServletResponse(response);
request.getRequestDispatcher(jspPage).forward(request, bufferedHttpServletResponse);
String xmlData = bufferedHttpServletResponse.getData();
```

This is what i am using along with `modelAndView` my  `anyChart` component require data in XML file,this file should be generated dynamically but it says response is already committed.

Comment: Are you using plain Servlets/JSPs or Spring-MVC? How do you generate your XML?

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `Servlet` and directly print out the answer:

```
public void service(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response){
response.setContentType("text/xml;charset=UTF-8");
PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
writer.append("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>");
writer.append("<result>");
// print your result
writer.append("</result>");
```

It's not from within a JSP, but it almost looks like you are already inside a `Servlet`.

If you are using Spring Web MVC, what your referral to modelAndView suggests, you might just want to use a method in your controller with `@ResponseBody`annotation on the return type.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/xmlresponse", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody ResultObjectWithJaxbAnnotations gernerateXmlResult() {
```

Don't forget `<mvc:annotation-driven />` in your Spring application-context - but you will have that most likely already.